# Using HTML Helper to create views is better than using direct HTML? Considering performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I want to know if there is a significant performance difference between HTML Helpers, or direct HTML to construct views, using Razor view engine and native methods such as Html.LabelFor(), Html.TextBoxFor().

Is there any case that I should avoid using HtmlHelpers (performance-wise)?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the helper-methods when building forms. I also prefer **not** using the Html.TextboxFor(), 99% of the time I use Html.EditorFor() for editors.

So, I build a form like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.SomeField)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.SomeField)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.SomeField)
```

This gives me a lot:
It makes sure all my fields have the right names and ID's, and it enables the use of client validation, without me having to write a lot of additional markup.

The use of Html.EditorFor()-methods instead of Html.TextboxFor(), gives me an opportunity to use the right editor for the right field.
An email-field should use a type="email" and a date should use type="date". Not a type="text". With EditorFor(), I could make templates, where I would use TextboxFor() or just plain markup. This way every model with an email-field, will get the same editor, and every date, will get the same datepicker.

So in short:
Always use LabelFor(), EditorFor() and ValidationMessageFor() if you are not using EditorForModel(). If you need special markup, use templates.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the helpers the way they should be used, it should be fairly trivial for the designers to learn how to use. Just remember that the goal is to keep things simple, if they end up making things more complex, it means they are not being used correctly.

the performance difference is negligible

Comment: Yes, I am refering to @Html.LabelFor(), @Html.TextBoxFor() methods

Comment: Exactly. These helpers provides you a simple way for codifying views and avoid to write complex and easy forgettable HTML code.

Comment: Yes.  Developer cycles cost way more than CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer regarding performance but I do have an answer to your last question.

> Is there any case that I should avoid using HtmlHelpers?

In our projects we tend to avoid using HtmlHelpers because static methods (such as Html helper extension methods) are hard to unit test in the way we'd like to.

Instead of using HTML Helpers (Extension methods) we have a custom base class for our views. This base class exposes our helper services (Uri, Html, DataEndpoint) and keeps things testable.